# Vert.x: retrieve records from database

Tags: vert.x

I have method called `selectAll` which has to return records selected from database, but when I want to return them as String it doesn't allow it and gives me:

`Local variable S defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.`

I tried to add final to my String but it stills the same.

Here is my `selectAll()` method:

```
public String selectAll(String table, String order) {
  String S;
  S = "";
  this.getCnx().getConnection(res -> {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
      SQLConnection connection = res.result();
      connection.queryWithParams(ReqSql.SELECT_ALL, new JsonArray().add(table).add(order), (ar) -> {
        if (ar.failed()) {
          this.sendError(500, response);
        } else {
          JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
          ar.result().getRows().forEach(arr::add);
          S = ar.result().getRows().toString();
          response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(arr.encode());
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

public AsyncSQLClient getCnx(){
     JsonObject mySQLClientConfig = new JsonObject()
            .put("host", "localhost")
            .put("database", "test")
            .put("username", "test")
            .put("password", "test")                    
            .put("port", 3306);

     return MySQLClient.createShared(vertx, mySQLClientConfig);
}
```

And I create another class for my requests:

```
public class ReqSql {
  public static final String SELECT_ALL = "SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY ? ASC";
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you need to declare local variables as `final` if you want to use them in a Lambda expression. But you cannot assign a value to a final variable. So this will not work:

```
final String S = "";

this.getCnx().getConnection(res -> {
  //...
  S = ar.result().getRows().toString();
  //...
});
```

Vert.x is highly asynchronous. That means that most operations, like `getConnection()`, will infect return immediately but their results, in this case `SQLConnection`, will be available to the `Handler` to a later point in time.

If you try to make a asynchronous result available in the main program flow that wouldn't work. What every you want to do with `S` is probably wrong. So if you don't need `S` afterwards I would convert `S` to a local variable.

I suggest you read about `Future` in the [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination). A `Future` is a placeholder for results of asynchronous calls. Vert.x is full of asynchronous calls. With `Future` you can do something like this:

```
Future<SQLConnection> connection = Future.future();
this.getCnx().getConnection(res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    logger.info("Got a connection.");
    connection.complete(res.result());
  } else {
    connection.fail(res.cause());
  }
});
```

You specify a `Handler` on a `Future` for retrieving the asynchronous result in a much more readable manner than callbacks/Lambdas:

```
connection.setHandler(res -> {
  ...
})
```